# Как правильно обработать исключение в данном случае?

Tags: java, spring, aop

У меня есть Аспект. И есть совет (метод(`loggingService`)), который я применю к своему целевому методу, которому я передам управление через `proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();`

И при этом у меня сам целевой метод может выбросить исключение, скажем, к примеру, какой-нибудь там `SomeExeption`.
Как мне правильней его обрабатывать, оборачивать? Первый вариант или второй? Или вообще как-то по-другому.

1)

```
public Object loggingService(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
    LOGGER.info("Before invoking  method" + " " + "\"" + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName().toString() + "\"");
    Object value = null;
    try {
        value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(); 
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error during execution method");
        throw new Throwable(e);
    }
    LOGGER.info("After invoking  method");
    return value;
}
```

2)

```
public Object loggingService(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws SomeException {
    LOGGER.info("Before invoking  method" + " " + "\"" + proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName().toString() + "\"");
    Object value = null;
    try {
        value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(); 
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error during execution method");
        throw new SomeException(e);
    }
    LOGGER.info("After invoking  method");
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку ваш сервис занимается исключительно логированием и не обладает никакой информацией о том, что делать с исключениями, то все исключения нужно выбрасывать как есть, без всяких изменений и оборачиваний. В противном вы можете получить необработанные исключения, или сзасветить ваш loggingService в стэктрейсе, что совершенно ни к чему.

```
try {
    value = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed(); 
} catch (Throwable e) {
    LOGGER.error("Error during execution method");
    throw e; // пробрасываем оригинальное исключение дальше без изменения стектрейса
}
```

Comment: А что произойдет тогда, когда моей целевой метод выбросит SomeException?
Вообще у меня это сервис слой, который дергает методы ДАО слоя.
И я логирую этот сервис слой. 
Вот и что будет тогда когда наш целевой метод сервис слоя выбросит свое исключение?
Его же нужно будет где-то обрабатывать?
А если мы не будем обарачивать?

Comment: Суть в том, что это исключение из сервис слоя пойдет дальше, на уровень выше.
 
Я также оборачиваю SQLException в ДАО слое в свое исключение и пробрасываю его дальше.
Если что, так его оборачивает исключение верхнего уровня, и так далее. Так вот, я просто не совсем понимаю, как это работает с аспектами.

Comment: Если не оборачивать - получите вместо ответа сервиса - стектрейс))

Comment: Допустим у вас может быть прикручен к сервису какой-нибудь ErrorHandler, который будет перехватывать любое исключение и в итоге формировать ответ для клиента. Все зависит от того, ЧТО вы хотите сделать при исключениях

Comment: Я же говорю, в данном случае, как  я вам описал, я хочу его пробросить дальше.

Comment: @AntonDorogokupets когда ваш целевой метод выбросит SomeException, это исключение полетит выше, и обработается (если у вас есть обработчик) выше. Суть в том, что логирующий слой, тем более прикрученный с помощью AOP не обладает никакими знаниями о логике программы, а потому не может принимать решение, что делать с исключениями.

Comment: @andreycha Суть в том, что это исключение будет обрабатываться в приложение на высшем уровне, мне нужно его просто пробросить дальше, на уровень выше, если оно возникнет. И как мне при этом правильно сделать, когда я к своему целевому методу применяю аспект?

Comment: @AntonDorogokupets обновил ответ.